# Is there a way to see if MySQL database has been accessed through SQL Injection attack?

Tags: mysql, sql-injection

I recently discovered that my website had a page with a SQL Injection vulnerability. Upon testing, it was easily exploitable with a pentesting tool like `sqlmap`. How do I figure out if the site database has been accessed with a SQL Injection attack, possibly exploiting this loophole? The server is running `Apache/2.4.18` and `MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.16`.

Comment: The most obvious way would be to check the access logs of Apache. These    are most often found under `/var/log/apache2`.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's not really a sure way to detect an SQL injection attack.

Some methods that approximate detection rely on keeping a "whitelist" of known legitimate SQL queries that your applications run. Then if the query logs contain any that are not known, that's potentially an clue that they came from an illicit source. Or else they could have been run by the DBA in a query tool.

It also requires that you log every SQL query, and that you had prepared the whitelist of known good queries.

As @alexn commented above, you could review your Apache logs (if you suppose the SQL injection came directly from an http request, which not all SQL injection vulnerabilities do). To do this, you would search for all the http requests in the logs that could have exploited the vulnerability you say you found in your code, and then with that search result, filter out all those that look like they had legitimate requests (e.g. `?id=123` is good, but `?id=123 OR 1=1` is suspicious).

There are other products monitor query traffic and try to guess whether an SQL query is legitimate or a suspicious query while they're happening, but these are prone to false positives and false negatives.

Comment: Thanks for the descriptive answer! I had enabled logging of all queries so I can (hopefully) go through that. Is there anyway to map those queries to the IP address they came from so that I can blacklist those IPs?

Comment: The query log has the IP of the client that submitted the query, but MySQL's "client" is the host that runs your application, not the host of the user. The user's IP is in the Apache log. It typically very hard to correlate the MySQL logs with the Apache logs, unless your request traffic is so infrequent that you have just one or fewer requests per second.

Answer (score 0):

Without proper logging there is no way to check that.
To mitigate risks, I advise to change passwords and tell your users to change their passwords.